# MySQL and MongoDB hybrid deployement

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a MySQL database with neat relations between the various tables. However, I have the following problem.

So, the table structure is as follows,

**Table Person**: *name, SSN*

**Table Account**: *accountNo, bank*

**Table C**: *person_id, account_id, propA, propB, propC*

**Table D**: *person_id, account_id, propA*

**Table E**: *person_id, account_id, probA, propB, propC, propD, propD*

Essentially, **Person** and **Account** have a fixed structure and these two tables are also part of a larger MySQL database which fit pretty well in a MySQL schema so MySQL is a good choice for them, but there may be many tables that connect tables Person and Account (here labelled as A, B, C, D, E). These tables can have any kind of and any number of properties (which seems to be a perfect use case for Mongo), but they also have 2 foreign keys *person_id and account_id*, so they need to be part of MySQL.

Currently, I am planning to keep a single MySQL table for all A, B, C, D, E with fields person_id, account_id and id, since all the Tables will have this.

Next I will have individual mongoDB documents for each of A, B, C, D, E which will contain the prop1, prop2, etc.

Table A = Table SQL + Table AMongo

**Table SQL**: *person_id, account_id, id*

**Table AMongo**: *prop1, prob2, prob3*

I will link AMongo and SQL with *id*

Is my thinking process correct? Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: In my view, that's the correct way to handle such scenarios. As you have SQL as you primary DB for storing account, person data and on the other hand, you have MongoDB for storing different properties which will be identified by the unique id from SQL record

Comment: Did you know that MySQL 8 supports the JSON datat type (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)? In most situation I recommending to avoid the mix up of the different DB's. You can do it only if you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @Neodan where am I using JSON in the MySQL table, it just has person_id, account_id and id fields, all of which are integers.

Comment: @coda The native JSON data type in the MySQL (from v. 5.7.9) allows to you have a dynamic table schema (partial schemaless), because you can operate with data from the JSON column in the SQL level (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html).

Comment: Ohh I am sorry, I missed out on the "Did you know" part. I thought you were telling my bad. I am using MySQL 5.6 :(. But thanks for the information.